# How did Canadian politicians bypass the Canada U.S. border closure in December 2020, to vacation in the U.S?

Tags: covid-19, canada

I'm referring to https://calgaryherald.com/news/politics/a-violation-of-trust-alberta-doctors-decry-government-vacations-abroad. I know there are exceptions to the Canada U.S. border closure, like back in Sept. 2020 for NHL players in Calgary and Toronto. But I don't think any of these vacations qualify?

[image]

If you know other Canada politicians who side stepped the border closure, just edit this post and add them.

Comment: While the land border may be closed, the US is not actually closed for most arriving passengers, right? For example, the [IATA TravelCentre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) doesn't list Canada as a restricted origin for travel to the US (when you click on the US on the map in the link).

Comment: The article itself is focused on "A violation of Trust" not a breach of the law. There doesn't appear to be any suggestion in the article that this travel was illegal, just hypocritical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what mode exactly each person used but where I live there has been nearly constant helicopter traffic from Canada to the local airport.  In addition to the flight, the operator of the helicopter service has teamed up with a trucking company to ship vehicles across the border that are dropped at the airport.

Here's an article: https://verticalmag.com/news/great-lakes-helicopter-helps-canadian-snowbirds-fly-south/

Seems like a major loophole to me.

Answer (score 3):

The border closure affects land crossings outside designated categories [like commercial freight trucks](https://www.ttnews.com/articles/us-canada-extend-border-closing-trucking-remains-exempt) or exceptional circumstances of some sort (which would not include holidays).

Air travel is still allowed which is [gamed in some cases](https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/snowbirds-canada-u-s-border-drive-winter-travel-covid-19-1.5810104).

A politician going to any of the destinations shown would most likely fly.  Especially to Hawaii ;-)

No laws were broken, but considerable cynicism towards rules was displayed.  A number of politicians have had to resign, starting with [Rod Phillips, Ontario's Finance Minister](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-55503789) who flew to St. Barths, which oddly enough, [seems to have fireplaces](https://twitter.com/rodphillips01/status/1342131118993190914).

[image]

(from my last link:)

> Ontario Finance Minister Rod Phillips resigned on Thursday after returning from a two-week vacation in St. Barts, where he had been since Dec. 13.

Jason Kenney, Alberta's Premier, first only scolded his errant flock, but has now [penalized some of them](https://www.citynews1130.com/2021/01/04/alberta-politicians-resign-holiday-travel/).

This [article](https://globalnews.ca/news/7551438/canadian-politicians-vacation-coronavirus/) lists some of the others.